# Showing all events in jquery full calendar for the week view but not the month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar, fullcalendar

I'm using the jquery [fullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) for a project. I only show the MONTH view and the WEEK view. In the month view, I only want to show max 4 events per day, but in the week view I want to display all the events for that day.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qe53etk5/6/

Here's how I call the plugin:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            eventLimit: 1,
            defaultDate: '2014-06-12',
            defaultView: 'basicWeek',
            editable: true,
            events: []
        });
```

As you can see, I put a limit but it's more for the month view...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the docs [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/eventLimit/) and [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View_Option_Hash/). You can do this with the view option hashes.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventLimit: {
        'month': 4, // adjust to 4 only for months
        'default': false // display all events for other views
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice it works! Thanks a bunch, can't believe I missed that. Here is the updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qe53etk5/7/

Answer (score 1):

for fullCalendar 2.x use the following:

```
        views: {
            month: {
                eventLimit: 2
            },
            agenda: {
                eventLimit: {
                    default: false
                }
            }
        },
```

see [View-Specific Options](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/View-Specific-Options/) for details

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?

Comment: no. I added a link to the documentation. it's self evident.